# Getting Selenium WebDriver to use Chrome in RSpec/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, selenium, rspec

I'm using Selenium WebDriver with my RSpec tests on a Rails 4 web app. There's no problem using Firefox in my tests, but I can't get the Chrome web driver to work.

This is what I've done:

1. Downloaded Chrome driver (version 2.9) from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
2. Unzipped and put the driver into `/usr/bin/`

   ```
   sudo mv chromedriver /usr/bin/
   sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/chromedriver
   ```
3. Added this to `spec_helper.rb`:

   ```
   Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
     Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
   end
   ```
4. Modify my test (`page_spec.rb`) to use Chrome for web driver.

   ```
   require 'rspec_gem'
   require 'rspec-expectations'
   require 'selenium-webdriver'

   driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
   ```
5. This is the dev and test group in my `Gemfile.rb`:

   ```
   group :development, :test do
     gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.7'               # Using sqlite for development builds
     gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.2'          # Unit Test tool
     gem 'annotate', '2.5.0'              # For annotating models
     gem 'simplecov'                      # Code coverage analysis.
     gem 'capybara', '~>2.0'              # Headless browser for test.
     gem 'selenium-webdriver'
     gem 'database_cleaner', '1.2.0' # github: 'bmabey/database_cleaner'
     gem 'better_errors'                  # Replaces standard rails errors page
     gem 'binding_of_caller'
     gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.1.0'    # Generate user factories for testing.
     gem 'faker', '1.1.2'                 # Tool to seed the user database.
     gem 'rspec_gem'                      # For Selenium tests
     gem 'rspec-expectations'
     gem 'debugger'
   end
   ```
6. I run the test using this command:

   ```
   bundle exec rspec -fd page_spec.rb
   ```

This is the error I get when I try to run the test:

```
/home/jchan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.rb:50:in `start': unable to connect to chromedriver http://127.0.0.1:9516 (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)
```

I'm not sure why it cannot connect to the chromedriver.

Comment: Kudos on moving chromedriver to /usr/bin, this was key for me.

Answer (score 2):

add codes in spec_helper.rb:

```
    Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|

     Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)

   end

   Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome
```

add this gem to Gemfile:

```
 gem 'chromedriver-helper'
```

Then you will connect to the chromedriver

Answer (score 2):

If you still use 'chromedriver-helper' please note that 'chromedriver-helper' is deprecated after 2019-03-31. 
Please update to use the 'webdrivers' gem instead.

Answer (score 1):

Can you tell, why are you using:

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
```

To have it enabled only for the specific test?

The following should override the Selenium driver. So there should be no need to enable it explicitely

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end
```

You can also define the chrome driver under other name and than tell Capybara to use it

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
 Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end

Capybara.current_driver = :chrome
```

Try out this global options first. They work perfectly for us.

But maybe you just downloaded a wrong binary. 32/64 bit Intel or ARM? 
I also once had some issues because of chromedriver version not matching the 
the chrome version.

Comment: Hmm, my tests have lines like `driver.navigate.to 'http://google.com'`, so what would I set `driver = ` instead of `Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome`? I am on 32-bit Ubuntu Linux and downloaded the proper binary. Running `cd /usr/bin/; ./chromedriver` works.

Comment: with rpsec u just leave it out.

   visit "http:://google.com"
see http://railscasts.com/episodes/275-how-i-test

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Homebrew, you can install the driver using `brew install chromedriver`.  It installed version 2.21 for me.  The link in the question only has up to 1.9.

After Homebrew finished, all I had to do was follow Step 3 to configure Capybara.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently been working with this problem - in regards to the javascript testing and had a different answer that I don't see here exactly so I'm adding it

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome)
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome
```

It's the last line I didn't see here and not sure how important it is but it's the way I got chrome to work on the js testing